# Is an apiKey absent in Google Maps API V3?

Tags: android, maps, api-key

[Here](http://code.google.com/intl/pl-PL/apis/maps/faq.html#keysystem) I saw a line, saying "Note: Google Maps API keys are only required when using the JavaScript Maps API V2 and the Maps API for Flash." And there is already a [Maps API V3](http://code.google.com/intl/pl-PL/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/). Does it mean I don't need an apiKey in MapView tag anymore? Can you provide some code samples with it's usage? Removing an `android:apiKey` line from MapView seems not smart...
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you found anything please? (Since July :\ ;))